# convert analog voltage to pwm

Tags: voltage, pwm

My car's dashboard lighting uses six B9 base incandescent bulbs .  The brightness of these bulbs is controlled through a wire-wound variable-resistance potentiometer with an output of 0-12VDC.  This is an antique vehicle with basic, non-modern, non-electronic wiring.

I want to replace the incandescent bulbs with LED bulbs also having B9 bases without having to add an additional control, just using the present controller.

Is there a device I can add to the potentiometer output that will convert the variable (0-12VDC) voltage to PWM to drive the bulbs?  It would go in the green wire in this diagram:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: The "potentiometer" is marked as a rheostat in the diagram. Are you sure that it gives out a variable voltage that doesn't greatly depend on the load? Anyway, many microcontrollers (for instance any Arduino like device) will be able to convert a voltage to a PWM signal, but you're going to need additional circuitry to drive any significant load, especially if you're dealing with voltages exceeding 5V.

Comment: Why are you insisting on PWM? Efficiency? If you are willing to tolerate a lower efficiency figure, a simple current source tied to the potentiometer should be just fine and very, very easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for something off the shelf and not looking to construct a circuit from scratch.

Fan speed controllers are commercially available that can drive 12v led bulbs instead of fans.  I would recommend using something like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/Pixnor-Controller-Adjustable-Reversible-reversing/dp/B01H1W79S0/ref=pd_sim_60_7?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=JX2HZEZDTSYRJ3TG651Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H1W79S0)

And replacing the existing potentiometer with the one mounted on the board.  It would also be possible to use the existing potentiometer (assuming it is a 3 terminal potentiometer not a 2 terminal rheostat) by either disconnecting it from all current wiring and wiring it to the board, or using a resistive divider to change the output voltage range of on the orange wire to what the board expects.  If you want to go this way, post a follow up and I will post instructions on how to figure out what resistors to use.

Note that you don't want to use a fan speed controller rated for 12 or 15v because the voltages on car electrical systems can exceed the nominal 13.5V the alternator/generator outputs significantly when the engine is turned off.